# How to make this box work with <a href>

Tags: html, hyperlink

My Code:

```
<a id="entire" href="/check-appointment.php">
    <div id="check_box">
        <div id="check_content">
            <a id="boxis" href="/check-appointment.php">I am a sales rep</a>
            <br> making a request on behalf of the client.
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
 #check_box {
 width:423px;
 height:250px;
 margin-left:100px;
 margin-top:10px;
 }
 #check_content {
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:37px;
 }
```

Problem:

I am unable to make the  work with the  I am trying to get that entire div to be part of the

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an HTML5 DocType it should work, anything before that won't allow inline elements `a` to wrap block level elements `div`.

Even if you use an anchor unless you do some z-indexing then your inner link likely won't be seen how you are expecting...since it's the same link it shouldn't be a problem, but that then becomes repetitive.

Comment: Can you post some of your CSS and markup in a JSFiddle? Does it work in any browsers or none at all?

Comment: ok posted css and it doesn't work on any browsres.  i am on a mac and also checked windows

Comment: After playing around with it, the issue is related to the inner link. Try removing the anchor inside the div's and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Also if i have two <a tags> for two boxes running side by side the hover effect that i have for the boxes doesn't seem to work,